# How can I efficiently retrieve a large number of database settings as PHP variables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, settings

Currently all of my script's settings are located in a PHP file which I 'include'. I'm in the process of moving these settings (about 100) to a database table called 'settings'. However I'm struggling to find an efficient way of retrieving all of them into the file.

The settings table has 3 columns:

- ID (autoincrements)
- name
- value

Two example rows might be:

```
admin_user            john
admin_email_address   john@example.com
```

The only way I can think of retrieving each setting is like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name = 'admin_user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$admin_user = $row['value'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM settings WHERE name = 'admin_email_address'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$admin_email_address = $row['value'];
```

etc etc

Doing it this way will take up **a lot** of code and will likely be slow.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually, setting up settings (oh, what an expression) is much faster with including these as a PHP script, than reading and parsing them from database. I understand the motivation - after all databases are for data - but in this case, you can save on speed and implementation. PHP is a virtual machine, and a pretty fast one at that - when you include a script, it is run in no time.

Comment: Even better, have you considered GENERATING a PHP script that sets up the settings (pardon again) by PHP, from a database? That is, if your settings do not change very often, or you change them in a very predictable fashion, and these just are in database for convenience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

100 settings? Load them all at once. That will take no time at all. You *absolutely* do not want to load them one at a time.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM settings');
$settings = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $settings[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
}
```

If you need to compartmentalize these somehow, depending on how you need to do it, you could put a category or something on the table and then just load all the settings in a particular category.

What I would suggest is abstracting this behind an object of some kind:

```
class Settings {
  private $settings;

  public function __get($name) {
    if (!$this->settings)) {
      $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM settings');
      $this->settings = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $this->settings[$row['name']] = $row['value'];
      }
    }
    return $this->settings[$name];
  }
}
```

This way the settings aren't loaded until you try and access one:

```
$settings = new Settings;
echo $settings->admin_name; // now they're loaded
```

Comment: 100 settings isn't really worth putting them into a database, either. Just use a file that says `<?php $admin_user = 'john'; $admin_email_address = 'john@example.com'; ?>` etc.

Comment: I can understand to put settings in the database, not really a problem. It's easier to change them with an administration interface.

100 settings is really not large. In addition to what cletus said, I suggest to add a cache system somewhere in between.
Considering one of your page doesn't have to reach the database (because it doesn't need or because it also use cached items), you would gain a lot of time (yes, a connection to database is slow).

Answer (score 1):

Well I seem to have figured it out:

```
$settings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($settings)) {
eval('global $' . $row['name'] . ';');
eval('$' . $row['name'] . ' = "' . $row['value'] . '";');
}
```

It works although I wasn't keen on using eval(), but I think it's the only way.

I'm now wondering whether many hosts have eval() disabled. Any thoughts?

Comment: just use the code cletus gave you. also consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/faq to make sure you understand how SO works.

Comment: I had another look at cletus's code and I got it working. Thanks a lot cletus. I think it's going to mean updating every case where my settings are already used but I'm sure it will be worth it in the long term. I will read the SO FAQ.